# Give external path in @Value Spring annotation and Resource

Tags: spring-boot

In spring boot application how do I give an external windows path using  `@Value` Spring annotation and Resource

The below example works fine that look into resources folder but I want to give the path outside of application like `c:\data\sample2.csv`

```
@Value("classPath:/sample2.csv")
private Resource inputResource;
...
  @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Employee> reader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<Employee> itemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<Employee>();
        itemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
        itemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        itemReader.setResource(inputResource);
```

and if I want to get the value from properties file in annotaion, whats the format to put the path in windows?
i tried these, none of them worked:

in code

```
@Value("${inputfile}")
```

in properties file:

```
inputfile="C:\Users\termine\dev\sample2.csv"
inputfile="\\C:\\Users\\termine\\dev\\sample2.csv"
inputfile="C:/Users/termine/dev/sample2.csv"
inputfile="file:\\C:\Users\termine\dev\sample2.csv"
inputfile="file://C://Users//termine///dev//sample2.csv"
```

Comment: instead of classPath: use @Value("file:/sample2.csv")

Comment: thank you this worked .. i can give full path after ..file:

Comment: and if I want to get the value from properties file in annotaion, whats the format to put the path in windows?
i tried these, none of them worked:

in code
```
@Value("${inputfile}")
```

in properties file:
```
inputfile="C:\Users\termine\dev\sample2.csv"
inputfile="\\C:\\Users\\termine\\dev\\sample2.csv"
inputfile="C:/Users/termine/dev/sample2.csv"
inputfile="file:\\C:\Users\termine\dev\sample2.csv"
inputfile="file://C://Users//termine///dev//sample2.csv"

```

Comment: glad to hear that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use classpath spring will try to search with the classpath even if you provide the outside file path.

so instead of using **classpath:** you can use **file:**

Ex.

```
 @Value("file:/sample2.csv") //provide full file path if any
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the key `spring.config.location` in properties to set the config location. Spring-boot will by default load properties from the locations, with precedence like below :

- A `/config` subdir of the current directory.
- The current directory
- A classpath `/config` package
- The classpath root

and apart from this when you start the jar or in application.properties you can provide the location of the config file like :

```
$ java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/default.properties,classpath:/override.properties
```

Answer (score 1):

You can serve static files from the local disk, by making the resource(s) "sample2.csv" as a static resource. An easy way to do this is by adding spring.resources.static-locations configuration to your applicaiton.properties file. Example:

```
spring.resources.static-locations=file:///C:/Temp/whatever/path/sample2.csv",classpath:/static-files, classpath:/more-static-resource
```

When I did this in one of the projects, I was able to access the file form the browser using localhost:8080/sample2.csv.

Comment: thank you z atef. 
and if I want to get the value from properties file in annotaion, whats the format to put the path in windows?
i tried these, none of them worked:

in code
```
@Value("${inputfile}")
```

in properties file:
```
inputfile="C:\Users\termine\dev\sample2.csv"
inputfile="\\C:\\Users\\termine\\dev\\sample2.csv"
inputfile="C:/Users/termine/dev/sample2.csv"
inputfile="file:\\C:\Users\termine\dev\sample2.csv"
inputfile="file://C://Users//termine///dev//sample2.csv"

```